# iup programs Crashes in IupOpen(argc, argv);

Tags: c, user-interface, iup

I try to use IUP in c

I test this example

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iup/iup.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  Ihandle *dlg, *label;
  IupOpen(argc, argv);
  label =  IupLabel("Hello world from IUP.");
  dlg = IupDialog(IupVbox(label, NULL));
  IupSetAttribute(dlg, "TITLE", "Hello World 2");
  IupShowXY(dlg, IUP_CENTER, IUP_CENTER);
  IupMainLoop();
  IupClose();
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I Compile it Like this

```
gcc q.c -liup -o q
```

And gcc gives me this

```
q.c: In function â€کmainâ€™:
q.c:6:3: warning: passing argument 1 of â€کIupOpenâ€™ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   IupOpen(argc, argv);
   ^
In file included from q.c:2:0:
/usr/include/iup/iup.h:35:11: note: expected â€کint *â€™ but argument is of type â€کintâ€™
 int       IupOpen          (int *argc, char ***argv);
           ^
q.c:6:3: warning: passing argument 2 of â€کIupOpenâ€™ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
   IupOpen(argc, argv);
   ^
In file included from q.c:2:0:
/usr/include/iup/iup.h:35:11: note: expected â€کchar ***â€™ but argument is of type â€کchar **â€™
 int       IupOpen          (int *argc, char ***argv);
           ^
```

When I run  the program its crashes.
Then I run it using gdb and gdb told me the program crashed it this line:

```
IupOpen(argc, argv);
```

I rtfm and stfw but I did not find the solution.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `IupOpen(argc, &argv);` instead of `IupOpen(argc, argv);` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should call IupOpen(&argc, &argv), that's what gcc is warning you.